# How to ensure the content expands/collapses without shifting the content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="hidContent">
    <div class="hidOverflow fullWidth">
        <div id="ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_CBExpServPage">
            <div class="header"><span><img src="theImages/arrow_right.png" id="imgType" />This is the first clickable link</span></div>
            <div class="content hidContent">
                <tfText01>
                    <p style="padding: 20px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); line-height: 23px; font-size: 14px; text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 1px 1px 1px; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;">It offers you the following convenient features:</p>
                    <ul style="padding-left: 45px; border: 0px; list-style: none; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: small;">
                        <li style="padding: 5px; border: 0px; text-indent: -0.7px;">First UL list to get everything else working.</li>
                        <li style="padding: 5px; border: 0px; text-indent: -0.7px;">Second UL list to get everything else working.</li>
                    </ul>
                </tfText01>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/snf9kae9/1/

How can I modify the JQuery/HTML to align the `This is the first clikable link` vertically centered and prevent the shifting of the text when the image changes.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd try is putting the image inside a span and giving that fixed dimensions. Since I can't see why you have the inner span taking up the whole div, just use that

```
<div class="header"><span><img src="theImages/arrow_right.png" id="imgType" /></span>This is the first clickable link</div>
```

and add the styles

```
.header span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awdhjo3p/

of course change the height and width to what you want

Answer (score 1):

I made image float to left, and also added padding for left and right separately.

```
    #imgType {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
        float: left;
    }
```

how about this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/snf9kae9/3/

Comment: This works except the image when expanded moves up too much. +1 for the effort and helping me fix yet another issue.